# align bottom of div with no defined height

Tags: html, css

Trying to align the bottom of #top-btn to the top of the footer But I don'twant to define the height of #top-btn

html

```
<footer class="row">
    <a id="top-btn" href="">...</a>
</footer
```

css

```
#top-btn {
position: absolute;
display: block;
z-index: 1000;
right: 50px; 

bottom: ?;

text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 1.25em;
letter-spacing: 1px;
color: #fff;
padding: 16px 35px;
background-color: #d11e5d;
}
```

Comment: do you want the `#top-btn` above with your footer?

Comment: Just declare the button outside the `<footer>` - why are you overcomplicating things?

Comment: I want the button to go overtop the content that is above the footer, which is brought in dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use relative/absolute:

```css
footer {
  margin:2em;
  background:gray;
  position:relative;/* absolute child will use it as reference*/
  }
a {
  position:absolute;
  right:50px;
  bottom:100%;/* from its referent container, goes right on top of it, no matter parent's height's */
  background:yellow;
  }
```

```html
<footer class="row">
    <a id="top-btn" href="">...</a>
  <p>some text here?</p>
</footer>
<footer class="row">
  <p>some text here?</p>
    <a id="top-btn" href="">...</a>
  <p>some text here?</p>
  <p>some text here?</p>
</footer>
  <footer class="row">
  <p>some text here?</p>
    <a id="top-btn" href="">...</a>
  <p>some text here?</p>
</footer
```

Comment: that's what I'm looking for